# Magento2 swatch-renderer.js:1184 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateData' of undefined

Tags: magento2, configurable-swatches

I am getting `swatch-renderer.js:1184 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateData' of undefined` error on product details for some products. While debugging notice that I am getting an error to line `gallery.updateData(imagesToUpdate);` in swatch-renderer.js And because of that `swatch.initialized` trigger not working for some products.

I have searched a lot but fail to get the correct answer.

Please suggest another way to solve this conflict

Comment: You should check the js, add js debugger, and then share what you have tried. There are several issues in swatch rendered, so it will difficult to answer.

Comment: Hi. Did you found any solution of your question? Please help me I have same issue.